# Is it possible to make a bit map image transparent in libreoffice?

Tags: bitmap, transparency, libreoffice

changing the transparency of the "area" in libreoffice draw/impress for a "picture" (bitmap) has no effect. Is is possible to change it? or is the only solution to create a gif image and add some alpha channel in eg. gimp?